# Prisma conditional foreign key

Tags: sql, node.js, database, postgresql, prisma

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

enum OwnerType {
  User
  Vehicle

  @@map("owner_type_enum")
}

model user {
  id                    String            @id @default(uuid()) 
  ownerType             OwnerType         @map("owner_type")
  fullName              String            @map("full_name") @db.VarChar(255) 
  updatedAt             DateTime          @updatedAt @map("updated_at")
  createdAt             DateTime          @default(now()) @map("created_at")
  documents             documents[]       @relation("driverId")

  @@unique([id, ownerType])
}

model vehicle {
  id             String      @id @default(uuid())
  ownerType      OwnerType   @map("owner_type")
  number         String
  users          user[]
  updatedAt      DateTime    @updatedAt @map("updated_at")
  createdAt      DateTime    @default(now()) @map("created_at")
  documents      documents[] @relation("transportCompanyId")

  @@unique([id, ownerType])
}

model documents {
  id               String            @id @default(uuid())
  user             user?             @relation(fields: [ownerId, ownerType], references: [id, ownerType], name: "driverId", map: "documents_fk_driver")
  vehicle          vehicle?          @relation(fields: [ownerId, ownerType], references: [id, ownerType], name: "transportCompanyId", map: "documents_fk_transportCompany")
  ownerId          String?           @map("owner_id")
  ownerType        OwnerType?        @map("owner_type")
  updatedAt        DateTime          @updatedAt @map("updated_at")
  createdAt        DateTime          @default(now()) @map("created_at")
  file             file[]
}
```

Documents model is possible a conditional foreign key based in ownerType?
In model documents need a column with foreign key that is an pk in user or vehicle.
Initially, the attempt was made to create conditional foreign keys in the documents table based on the ownerType. However, Prisma does not support this approach directly, leading to errors.

Alternative approaches were explored, such as creating separate tables for each owner type and associated junction tables, but these introduced complexity.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: Keeping two foreign keys like you seem to be doing now is a good solution. Consider a check constraint that makes sure that the correct foreign key is set and the other one is NULL.

Comment: The relationship you're describing with mutually exclusive reference types is called an arc relationship. The model you've presented is called a polymorphic association in Ruby on Rails. A problem with polymorhic associations is that PostgreSQL doesn't natively support them using foreign keys; however, they can be implemented using triggers and functions. Another approach is to use separate columns for each type with the appropriate foreign keys and check constraints to ensure that only one is non-NULL at a time. Each approach has trade-offs between complexity, extensibility, and performance.